# Read Oracle installed version from Registry

Tags: c#, windows, oracle, registry

I want to read installed Oracle versions of all remote machines. I know in registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE/inst_loc" there is an inventory.xml file from which versions can be read. In order to avoid reading xmls, is there any other way to read installed versions through key/value pair from registry using c#

Answer (score 1):

Version of Oracle is not available in Registry.

Your machine may have several Oracle clients installed. An "Oracle client" consist of many different components, in principle they all can have a different version. Reading the inventory file is not reliable, perhaps in case of "Oracle Instant Client" it is even not created - it is more like a log-file, nothing else.

What you can do is to search `PATH` folders for file `oci.dll` which is one of the core DLL of each Oracle client. Read out the version of this file.

```
foreach ( string folder in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';') ) {
   if ( File.Exists(Path.Combine(folder, "oci.dll")) ) {
      var oraFileVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(folder, "oci.dll"));
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found Oracle oci.dll Version {0}.{1}", oraFileVersion.FileMajorPart, oraFileVersion.FileMinorPart));
   }
}
```